(2-D Rigid Body Equilibrium) What mistake(s) am I making in my interpretation of the resultant moment?
The given problem is:

Determine the reactions on the bent rod which is supported by a smooth surface at B and by a collar at A, which is fixed to the rod and is free to slide over the fixed inclined rod.


I've set up three equations to solve for A and B: one for the horizontal components of the net force, one for the vertical, and one for the resultant moment. I have verified that my first two were accurate using a couple of other sources:
$$\sum F_x = \frac{4}{5}F_A-\frac{5}{13}F_B=0$$
$$\sum F_y = \frac{3}{5}F_A+\frac{12}{13}F_B-100=0$$
The issue appears when I write the resultant moment equation. It is evident that the most efficient way to do this is to pick either A or B as the arbitrary point about which to sum the moments (and set that sum equal to zero) as doing so allows for the force acting through that same point to be ignored entirely. However, I'm trying to see if I can use the "corner" of the rod (where the blue arrow is drawn) as the point instead. I'll call this point C. The equation I came up with (assuming a counterclockwise moment is positive) is:
$$(M_R)_C = -\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)(F_A)(6\mathrm ft)-\left(\frac{5}{13}\right)(F_B)(2\mathrm ft)+(100\mathrm{lb})(3\mathrm ft) -(200\mathrm{lb\cdot ft}) = 0$$
Having identified a system, I attempted to solve it using Gauss-Jordan elimination:
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
    \dfrac45 & -\dfrac{5}{13} & 0 \\[4pt]
    \dfrac{3}5 & \dfrac{12}{13} & 100 \\[4pt]
    -\dfrac{18}5 & -\dfrac{10}{13} & -100
  \end{array}\right]
\sim
  \left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
    \dfrac45 & -\dfrac{5}{13} & 0 \\[4pt]
    0 & \dfrac{63}{52} & 100 \\[4pt]
    0 & -\dfrac52 & -100
  \end{array}\right]
$$
only to find that the system is inconsistent. I double checked my matrix algebra (not as if it was particularly long or complicated) with a calculator and got the same result.
So my question is, where is the gap in my understanding? Was picking point C not a viable option for constructing the resultant moment equation?
Edit: I should note that both reactions can only take the form of a normal force, at least according to the information I was given.

Point C is a perfectly valid location to sum the moments around, but you're missing a moment term from the collar. In other words, whoever told you that a rigidly connected collar can't support a moment is wrong. Are you using Hibbeler? See connection type (9) here. You also have some unit confusion, but this is unrelated. This solution even appears on Youtube.

Generally, it's best practice to draw all constraints and then eliminate the ones for which elimination is clearly justified, rather than adding them one by one as you think of them, which makes it too easy to miss one.

@Chemomechanics Thanks for the input, and yes, the problem comes from Hibbeler (Statics and Mechanics of Materials 6th Ed). No, I wasn't told that the collar couldn't support a moment, I realize now that I had somehow overlooked the fact that the collar would act to prevent rotation. I think I took too quick of a glance at #7 on the chart of support structures, misinterpreted it to be the same type of collar in the problem, and used the corresponding description of "only a normal force" as applicable. It clicked after a while.

@Chemomechanics One other thing, is the unit confusion you mentioned my accidental use of "m" in the distance terms of the moment equation instead of ft?

Note that applied torques have no position information associated with them. You can move them around and the problem will not change.

You can get rid of the requirement for torque balance and the 3rd equation, and its complexity, by using the graphical method of solution:
First combine the applied load and torque into a single force, offset by $\frac{200\, {\rm ft\cdot lb}}{100\, {\rm lb}} =  2 {\rm ft}$ to the right, and recognize that the applied load can freely slide up and down along the line of action (dashed red below) but not left or right.

Also, recognize that the reaction at the collar A is a force $A$ perpendicular to the collar and a reaction moment at the collar. This means that the reaction force can slide along the collar as well as along its line of action, but the direction of the force is fixed.
Finally, the reaction at the contact at B is a force $B$ perpendicular to the surface that can only slide along its line of action.
This means that all the force can meet at the pivot point P and you can use geometry to find out where in space this is. But you can solve the problem without doing any geometry.

Notice how force $B$ has slid along the collar axis in order for the line of action of $A$ to pass through the point P defined by where the force $B$ meets the applied load.
Hence the three forces can be placed on a single point and the force balance is sufficient to solve the problem. For simplicity, the oblique forces are decomposed into horizontal and vertical components. Note that the torque balance is automatically satisfied as the net torque about point P is zero.

The two equations for the force balance are
$$ \begin{aligned} \tfrac{4}{5} A - \tfrac{5}{13} B & = 0 \\
   \tfrac{3}{5} A + \tfrac{12}{13} B - 100 & = 0
\end{aligned} $$
which you solve with your favorite method to get
$$ \begin{aligned}
 A & = \tfrac{2500}{63} \\
 B & = \tfrac{5200}{63}
\end{aligned} $$
The easiest thing is to use the first equation to substitute $A = \tfrac{25}{52} B$ into the second equation. Then solve $ \tfrac{63}{52} B - 100 = 0$ and use $B$ into the first equation to get $A$.
